# Cómo solucionar el que toda mi pc se volvió un repo de git?

Tags: windows, git, terminal

Hace un tiempo instalé un módulo desde la terminal cmd de win32 sin estar en un proyecto en específico y desde entonces cada que creo un nuevo proyecto aparece como rama `master` y aunque sea nuevo y no tenga nada dentro al hacer `git status` trae todas las carpetas superiores y nose como resolverlo. Agradecería mucho si alguien sabe como resolver esto.
Por ej creo una carpeta llamada Todo, abro el proyecto en visual y al dar git status en la terminal tengo esto:

```
acer@DESKTOP-C735VGH MINGW64 ~/Documents/Laboratoria/Todo (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../otro-proyecto/
        ../otro-proyecto/
        ../otro-proyecto/
        ../otro-proyecto/
        ../otro-proyecto/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Los `otros-proyectos` estan fuera de la carpeta Todo.

Comment: silvana, muestra los comandos y las salidas de los comandos (como texto, no pongas imágenes, plis) como parte de la pregunta para hacernos una idea de lo que tienes que hacer.... y bienvenida!

Comment: @eftshift0gracias, agregué la salida cuando creo un proyecto, eso aporta mas claridad al problema?

Comment: tenes una carpeta .git ocula en alguna carpeta padre de esa... rastreala...borrala y listo

Comment: Secundo a @gbianchi. Hay un directorio llamado `.git` en `~/Documents/Laboratoria`? Podrías verlo haciendo un `ls -la`, porque es un directorio oculto.

Comment: Esto debe servir para saber donde esta el directorio (podría estar en directorios más arriba de Laboratoria): `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

Comment: @eftshift0 es windows.. con ls no va a ver nada...

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, lo pude solucionar, tenía en ese Documents una .git/ y en el desktop también, me cuidaré de las carpetas ocultas, gracias!!!